# AES encryption with plain text key using bash openssl

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, aes

I am trying to encrypt a string using AES CBC. The output of the online tool (http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/) and the bash openssl command do not match. Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong?

`key = 12345678912345678912345678912345
iv="e90e89a2277f4f3b6a2080d27f734266" #using the one generated by online tool
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in input.txt -out output.txt -K $key -iv $iv`

EDIT - more info on the settings chosen on the site -

`Input type - plain text
Function - AES
Mode - CBC
Key - (plain) - 12345678912345678912345678912345
Init Vector - e9 0e 89 a2 27 7f 4f 3b 6a 20 80 d2 7f 73 42 66`

Comment: Why do you want it to match? Anyway, if you have a problem with the OpenSSL commandline tool, then you need to ask the question on [su].

Comment: I have been working on a POC using the online tool, and now when I wanted to code all things up, the outputs don't match. Thats why. I tried OpenSSL gems/libraries in ruby/python also, and they also give different results. So am pretty sure there's a fundamental mistake I am making.

Comment: Yes, the key is supposed to be hex encoded. Currently, your key is 32 characters long and consists of digits 1 through 9, so it *can* be interpreted as hex, but that would result in a 128 bit key which would be AES-128 and not AES-256.

Comment: are you suggesting using -aes-128-cbc? I tried that and outputs still dont match.

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that you hex-encode your key if you want AES-256. Besides, you haven't provided any information about which settings you chose on the site, so this is just guessing.

Comment: My bad. Updated description with settings used on site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93913/discussion-between-umang-and-artjom-b).

Comment: AES-128 or AES-256 is usually automatically chosen using the key size; this is certainly the case for OpenSSL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in odt-IV-e90e89a2277f4f3b6a2080d27f734266.dat -K "12345678912345678912345678912345" -iv "e90e89a2277f4f3b6a2080d27f734266" -nopad
```

and

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -d -in odt-IV-e90e89a2277f4f3b6a2080d27f734266.dat -K "12345678912345678912345678912345" -iv "e90e89a2277f4f3b6a2080d27f734266" -nopad
```

work for me for the file generated by the online calculator using [the following settings](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/link/40c865g8zDtMZmnwq/):

- Input type: Text
- Input(Plaintext): TESTTESTTESTTEST
- Function: AES
- Mode: CBC
- Key(HEX): 12345678912345678912345678912345
- Init. vector: e90e89a2277f4f3b6a2080d27f734266
- Operation: ENCRYPT

---

EDIT:

I confirmed that the online tool does [zero padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#Zero_padding), but openssl expects [PKCS#5 (also known as PKCS#7)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#PKCS7) padding:

> All the block ciphers normally use PKCS#5 padding also known as
>   standard block padding: this allows a rudimentary integrity or
>   password check to be performed. However since the chance of random
>   data passing the test is better than 1 in 256 it isn't a very good
>   test.

So the following argument is needed:

> -nopad         disable standard block padding

See e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/10523/25845).

---

Beware that your output plaintext will have up to 15 extra binary zero bytes (`\x00`)

---

EDIT2:

(I am sorry I misunderstood the question, thought you wanted to check the result of the online tool)

To perform the same operation as the online tool:

```
echo -n "TESTTESTTESTTEST" | openssl aes-128-cbc -e -K "12345678912345678912345678912345" -iv "e90e89a2277f4f3b6a2080d27f734266" -nopad > odt-IV-e90e89a2277f4f3b6a2080d27f734266-1.dat
```

This one uses `echo -n` to feed the input data. If you are not working on a system capable of this, you will have to prepare a file `input.txt`, which contains the string `TESTTESTTESTTEST` (please do check that its length is 16 bytes -- i.e. no newline at the end). Then use the `-in input.txt` option:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -in input.txt -e -K "12345678912345678912345678912345" -iv "e90e89a2277f4f3b6a2080d27f734266" -nopad > odt-IV-e90e89a2277f4f3b6a2080d27f734266-2.dat
```

---

When the message is not block-size aligned (i.e. its length is not divisible by 16 without a remainder) you have to apply [zero padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#Zero_padding) (append to end that many binary zeroes, to make it block-aligned).

So to [encrypt the string "TESTTESTTEST"](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/link/40e351gOhKnRXuxdY/) (its length is 12, you must add 4 binary zeroes to block-align it to 16):

```
echo -ne "TESTTESTTEST\x00\x00\x00\x00" | openssl aes-128-cbc -e -K "12345678912345678912345678912345" -iv "e90e89a2277f4f3b6a2080d27f734266" -nopad > odt-IV-e90e89a2277f4f3b6a2080d27f734266-3.dat
```

(The `-e` in `echo` enables interpretation of backslash escapes for the `\x00` to work)

---

EDIT3(bonus one):

To perform the zero padding using shell:

```
input="TESTTESTTEST"
( echo -n "${input}" ; head -c 15 /dev/zero ) | head -c "$((((${#input}+15)/16)*16))" | openssl aes-128-cbc -e -K "12345678912345678912345678912345" -iv "e90e89a2277f4f3b6a2080d27f734266" -nopad > odt-IV-e90e89a2277f4f3b6a2080d27f734266-4.dat
```

Comment: one question - why are you doing -d, when we want to encrypt? My requirement is to get the output b5 e227 717dab8a9f03c4e8a5f6e20296 with your specific example. And the key that I have is in plaintext.

Comment: @Umang sorry, misunderstood you...Please see the updated answer

Comment: @Umang Regarding key in plaintext -- you will have to convert it into hex e.g. `echo -n "12345678912345678912345678912345" | xxd -ps -c32` and use `aes-256-cbc` instead of `aes-128-cbc`

Comment: Just a note: The online tool performs zero padding on the key as well, i.e. [this](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/link/40e2cdgmPAc09DL61/) and [this](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/link/40e2d2ghVfTkZ8via/) yields the same result.

Comment: Thank you! Couldn't have asked for a better explanation. Really appreciate it! :)

Comment: The online tool uses JS to calculate, which may also need check itself, [testmgr](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/master/crypto/testmgr.h) has tvs to compare with.