# How to encrypt a message with AES encryption?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

I read this [article](https://torrentfreak.com/pirate-bays-mystery-aes-code-finally-decrypted-150112/) about the Pirate Bay's secret AES encrypted message being solved. (this is old news)

The solver used this command in his linux terminal to decrypt the message.

```
echo "JyO7wNzc8xht47QKWohfDVj6Sc2qH+X5tBCT+uetocIJcjQnp/2f1ViEBR+ty0Cz" | openssl aes-128-cbc -K $(printf wearetpb | sha256sum | head -c 32 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') -nosalt -nopad -iv 0 -base64 -d -p
```

The decrpyted message was a link: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YEG9DgRHhA`

---

I want to encrpyt my own custom message the same way the Pirate Bay did. I assume I would need to change the encrypted text to my custom message and change the command to encrypt, rather than decrypt. But how do I do this?

Comment: Don't forget to use another key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
echo -n "https://stackoverflow.com/q/39197703/5128464" | openssl aes-128-cbc -K $(printf wearetpb | sha256sum | head -c 32 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') -nosalt -iv 0 -e -base64
```

Giving ciphertext:

```
l3iwQZrEe8R55MQMu13Hn2S+MvKs46fLT6rVP3yiJqvCPwAzJLrnZph1fYX1qDkk
```

Which then can be decrypted (using the same technique, key, etc.):

```
echo "l3iwQZrEe8R55MQMu13Hn2S+MvKs46fLT6rVP3yiJqvCPwAzJLrnZph1fYX1qDkk" | openssl aes-128-cbc -K $(printf wearetpb | sha256sum | head -c 32 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') -nosalt -nopad -iv 0 -base64 -d
```

Giving back the plaintext:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/q/39197703/5128464
```

---

But if you look carefully at the original decrypted text (i.e. dump the actual message bytes):

```
echo "JyO7wNzc8xht47QKWohfDVj6Sc2qH+X5tBCT+uetocIJcjQnp/2f1ViEBR+ty0Cz" | openssl aes-128-cbc -K $(printf wearetpb | sha256sum | head -c 32 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') -nosalt -nopad -iv 0 -base64 -d | xxd -g1
```

You get this (please note the five '00' bytes at the end of output):

```
0000000: 68 74 74 70 73 3a 2f 2f 77 77 77 2e 79 6f 75 74  https://www.yout
0000010: 75 62 65 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 77 61 74 63 68 3f 76 3d  ube.com/watch?v=
0000020: 2d 59 45 47 39 44 67 52 48 68 41 00 00 00 00 00  -YEG9DgRHhA.....
```

And if you repeat the same for the previous result:

```
echo "l3iwQZrEe8R55MQMu13Hn2S+MvKs46fLT6rVP3yiJqvCPwAzJLrnZph1fYX1qDkk" | openssl aes-128-cbc -K $(printf wearetpb | sha256sum | head -c 32 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') -nosalt -nopad -iv 0 -base64 -d | xxd -g1
```

You get a different ending (this time there are five '05' bytes):

```
0000000: 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 73 74 61 63 6b 6f 76 65 72  http://stackover
0000010: 66 6c 6f 77 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 71 2f 33 39 31 39 37  flow.com/q/39197
0000020: 37 30 33 2f 35 31 32 38 34 36 34 05 05 05 05 05  703/5128464.....
```

Those bytes are called [padding bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Padding) and must be added as [AES cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) in [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29) can not process messages whose length is not N*128 bits (i.e. which can not be divided into 16-byte blocks)

The padding used in the original plaintext (i.e. `00 00 00 00 00`) is a [zero padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Zero_padding), but the second one (`04 04 04 04`) is a [PKCS7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) padding.

Unfortunately zero padding is not directly supported in the openssl command line utilities, so you have to add it manually (note the added zero bytes and an additional `-nopad` option):

```
echo -ne "https://stackoverflow.com/q/39197703/5128464\0\0\0\0\0" | openssl aes-128-cbc -K $(printf wearetpb | sha256sum | head -c 32 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') -nosalt -nopad -iv 0 -e -base64
```

Giving:

```
l3iwQZrEe8R55MQMu13Hn2S+MvKs46fLT6rVP3yiJquYbIGPlGOBxJxJmU/bXocR
```

You can check the padding of the new plaintext with:

```
echo "l3iwQZrEe8R55MQMu13Hn2S+MvKs46fLT6rVP3yiJquYbIGPlGOBxJxJmU/bXocR" | openssl aes-128-cbc -K $(printf wearetpb | sha256sum | head -c 32 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') -nosalt -nopad -iv 0 -base64 -d | xxd -g1
```

To see that the padding is correct now:

```
0000000: 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 73 74 61 63 6b 6f 76 65 72  http://stackover
0000010: 66 6c 6f 77 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 71 2f 33 39 31 39 37  flow.com/q/39197
0000020: 37 30 33 2f 35 31 32 38 34 36 34 00 00 00 00 00  703/5128464.....
```

---

If you wanted to generate the padding in the shell, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33468943/5128464) (under EDIT3).

Good luck!